# How can i catch a value into a variable with an ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular

My inquiry is just to know if there's some way to pass a value to a variable in the html file in angular. Here my code

```
 <div fxFlex="65" class="user-details" >
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
        <h4 class="user-name px-2">
          {{ user.nombres }} {{ user.apellidos }}
          </h4>

          **<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name">**

          <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">
                    <mat-icon>ballot</mat-icon>
          </button>

      </div>
```

All i need is to pass the value of {{user.nombres}} to the variable "name". This's because in the typescript file in angular the variable name is awaiting for this value to pass this same value to an interface and then to be displayed in a dialog component.

here the component paciente typescript code

```
import { DialogoPacienteComponent } from '../dialogo-paciente/dialogo- 
paciente.component';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from 
'@angular/material/dialog';
import { User } from '../users/user.model';
import { DataRowOutlet } from '@angular/cdk/table';

export interface DialogData {
name: string;
}

@Component({
selector: 'app-pacientes',
templateUrl: './pacientes.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./pacientes.component.scss'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
providers: [PacienteService]
})

export class PacientesComponent implements OnInit {

name: string;

constructor(
public appSettings: AppSettings,
public router: Router,
public usersService: PacienteService,
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
paciente: Paciente,
public dialog: MatDialog

) {
this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
}

ngOnInit() {
this.getUsers();
}

openDialog(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogoPacienteComponent, {
width: '250px',
data: {name: this.name},
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
console.log('The dialog was closed');
});
}
```

and again my code in the html where i got the value, i want to pass to
the variable "name" in the html and inmmediatly to the ts. or no matter
if i can pass it directly to the "name" in the ts. file, either one is
fine for me if it works.

```
<div
  *ngFor="
    let user of users
  <div fxFlex="65" class="user-details" >
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
       <h4 class="user-name px-2">
          {{ user.nombres }} {{ user.apellidos }}
       </h4>
    <div>
         **<!--here is where i need to catch the user.nombres value and 
         assign it to variable name or pass it directly to ts.file-->
         <input [(ngModel)]="name">**
    </div>
         <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">
            <mat-icon>ballot</mat-icon>
         </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

One more time thanks in advance,

Comment: You mean, you want to assign `user.nombres` to the `name` variable?

Comment: Cant you do `this.name = this.user.nombres` in the component, when `this.user.nombres` is updated?

Comment: I think, @ilpianoforte is right.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the `user` object is being updated via an observable, a method or such. Therefore, I suggest to simply update your `name` variable, in the same place where the `user` object is being update.

So I would simply place this line in the fitting place in the component:

```js
this.name = this.user.nombres;
```

and since `[(ngModel)]` is two-way binding, the change to `this.name` would be displayed in your template as well.

Based on the current information I would imagine this solves the question, unless I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: thank you so much for answer. Well, i add the complement of the code so you can see in more detail what i'm doing, but i already try as you mentioned this.name = this.user.nombres; but i doesn't work. or maybe i didn't know how to do it properly in the html file. thanks in advance

Comment: In the code you have added I cant see any variable called `users`. Could you please provide a Stackblitz demo? Perhaps its easier in that way.

Comment: yes, there is. let user of users in the html. i haven't used stackblitz before, give a chance to get involved. In the meant time, i can wait any answer. thanks bro

Comment: Yes i see `let user of users`. But in the code that you have provided for the component, i dont see a variable called `users` that you can iterate over. Maybe the code you provided is incomplete? Or you have forgotten to define a `users` variable in the component and that is causing your problem?